# Document view detect enclosing NSScrollView resize

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, nsscrollview

I have a custom view as the document view of an `NSScrollView`.

The document view needs to know how wide the scroll view is, to determine its own height and adjust drawing (wrapped content based on the width).

How can the document view watch for changes to the width of the enclosing scroll view?

Comment: So you don't "watch" for size changes, just set the appropriate autoresizingMask on the document view. ie. documentView.autoresizingMask = NSViewWidthSizable. And then your drawRect method will get called every time the size changes so it can redraw.

Comment: @rocky my view does not have a drawRect method, I'm using layers. The layers need to be moved when the width changes.

Comment: OK well how are you moving/drawing the layers right now?

Comment: @rocky I'm using the `layout` method, but it seems to be called inconsistently (works sometimes after a half second delay, other times doesn't get called at all). For debugging I've also wired up an NSButton to manually relayout after the window has been resized.

Comment: Observe the `NSViewFrameDidChangeNotification` notification?

Comment: Are you setting view.needsLayout = YES?

Comment: @Willeke I tried that, but even setting `self.postsFrameChangedNotifications` the notification still never gets called when my view is resized. It is called on other views during the same resize event, but watching them seems fragile? There must be a better way.

Comment: @rocky yes, that's set.